# Does bootstrap support column width equals to zero in order to hide grid column in extra small screens?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know I can do media query to detect screen size and add "`display:none`" style accordingly, but does bootstrap has a built-in class to hide a grid column for certain screen size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! And very flexible they are too. Have a look here:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

If that's not clear, I can try to help you work out which ones you need?